# Expo doesn't work after ejecting to ExpoKit

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am working with Expo app, and I need to eject this app to ExpoKit, to create p2p chat using [this library](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc). When I managed to eject my App (I got "Ejecting was succesful message" from Expo in my terminal, so I guess it was ok) using ExpoKit. And now, when I want to build my project, even just to taste if it's working (without changing code, that was working before eject using `expo start --lan`). Here's the fullstack trace of this error.

```
dolidod@debian:~/PROJECT_DIR/android$ ./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:823)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:774)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:568)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:625)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:787)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:773)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:568)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:625)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:787)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:773)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:568)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:625)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:281)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:276)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.doNewInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:172)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.newInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:99)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.<init>(DefaultRootBuildState.java:46)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildRegistry.addRootBuild(DefaultIncludedBuildRegistry.java:85)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:823)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:774)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:568)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:625)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:787)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:773)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:568)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:625)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:787)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:773)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:568)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:625)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:787)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:773)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:568)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:625)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:281)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:276)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServices.defaultScriptPluginFactory(BuildScopeServices.java:318)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory(BuildScopeServices.java:310)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:821)
        ... 63 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/dolidod/KORONAPIVOT/SkateAppFrontend/android/.gradle/4.10.2/fileHashes/fileHashes.lock (Permission denied)
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:110)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.incrementLockCount(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:106)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.acquireFileLock(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:165)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.onStartWork(DefaultCacheAccess.java:368)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:213)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:203)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.newCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:298)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.newCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:57)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.createCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:160)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.createCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:185)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CrossBuildFileHashCache.createCache(CrossBuildFileHashCache.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileHasher.<init>(CachingFileHasher.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter(BuildSessionScopeServices.java:161)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:821)
        ... 89 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/dolidod/KORONAPIVOT/SkateAppFrontend/android/.gradle/4.10.2/fileHashes/fileHashes.lock (Permission denied)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.filelock.LockFileAccess.<init>(LockFileAccess.java:33)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.<init>(DefaultFileLockManager.java:156)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:107)
        ... 107 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

After some tips, that Allan Joseph suggested: https://pastebin.com/0HPdKzba (I used pastebin, because of stackoverflow post body limitation).

Also, here are my AndroidManifest.xml permissions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
  package="host.exp.exponent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

  <permission
    android:name="skate.some.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

  <!-- These are required permissions to make the app run -->
  <uses-permission android:name="skate.some.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

  <!-- ADD PERMISSIONS HERE -->
  <!-- BEGIN OPTIONAL PERMISSIONS -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

  <!-- These require runtime permissions on M -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
  <!-- END OPTIONAL PERMISSIONS -->

  <!-- ADD TEST PERMISSIONS HERE -->

  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />

  <application
```

Also, here's my package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "@eva-design/eva": "^1.4.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.4",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "~3.2.1",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^2.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/routers": "^5.0.1",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "^4.4.1",
    "@ui-kitten/date-fns": "^4.4.1",
    "@ui-kitten/eva-icons": "^4.4.1",
    "@ui-kitten/moment": "^4.4.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "axois": "^0.0.1-security",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5.0.2",
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "expo-av": "~7.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "~7.0.0",
    "expo-document-picker": "~7.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~7.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~7.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker-multiple": "^1.1.5",
    "expo-multiple-imagepicker": "^1.0.6",
    "expo-secure-store": "~7.0.0",
    "expo-video-player": "^1.5.7",
    "expokit": "^35.0.4",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "native-base": "2.13.8",
    "npm": "^6.14.3",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-bottom-scroll-listener": "^3.0.0",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.20",
    "react-material-ui-form-validator": "^2.0.9",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-axios": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-device-uuid": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-dialog": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^3.2.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-form": "^2.1.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.28.0",
    "react-native-maps": "~0.25.0",
    "react-native-material-design-searchbar": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.16.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^6.5.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "~0.3.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~1.0.0-alpha.23",
    "react-native-search-bar": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-store-rating": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-svg": "~9.9.2",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-validator-form": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.0.2",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-native-webrtc": "^1.75.3",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.2",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-on-screen": "^2.1.1",
    "reconnecting-websocket": "^4.4.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.20",
    "url-search-params-polyfill": "^8.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.9.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-const-enum": "^0.0.1",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your manual installation for Android has been done properly for the library. Go through the link and verify it once again.

[Android Installation](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc/blob/master/Documentation/AndroidInstallation.md)

Also, your stack trace mentions Permissions denied on the below lines. Check if you have write permissions recursively applied to all directories in the project folder. If not give write and execute permissions to the directory.

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /home/dolidod/KORONAPIVOT/SkateAppFrontend/android/.gradle/4.10.2/fileHashes/fileHashes.lock
>   (Permission denied)
>
> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /home/dolidod/KORONAPIVOT/SkateAppFrontend/android/.gradle/4.10.2/fileHashes/fileHashes.lock
>   (Permission denied)

For Permissions use the below command on terminal

```
chmod -R 777 /project-folder-path
```

> For the other errors you updated

Go to project root folder and try the below commands. Make sure these are done in root folder not the android folder.

```
rm -rf node_modules

npm install -g expo-cli

npm install

expo start or npm start
```

Also check if you have added the below permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Jospeh - Okey, I followed your tips. I faced some errors, I tried googling them but nothing work. I guess it's some issue with versions, because nothings seems to work.

Comment: @DolidodTeethtard I have updated my answer based on what I saw on the stacktrace of the link you shared. Try it and let me know

Comment: I already had those permissions, I removed node_modules and installed packages (i am using yarn so i used "yarn add") as you shown in answer. However issue is still the same

Comment: Can you share your package.json file. I need to check that

Comment: Do `expo install expo-permissions` and `expo install expo-media-library` and re-run the project again

Comment: Hmm, i did excatly that and it keeps to crash (logs are excatly the same as before). I'll try to google that more.

Comment: I also had issue, that I resolved - my terminal where i run "expo start" told me something about wrong versions of those packages, so I installed correct versions, and error is still excatly the same.

Comment: Nah, error is still excatly the same (as in link that i put in my question)